# Count without duplicates Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a table like -

| Seller | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Ron | 0 |
| Jon | 12 |
| Ron | 12 |
| Jon | 13 |
| Harry | 121 |
| Saw | 0 |

I need to count the seller if its value is not zero and non-duplicate.

Here the seller count would be 2.

**Explanation** -

Since **Ron** is available twice but one time its value is 0 so we will eliminate it.
**Jon** has value but it appears twice thus we count it as **1**.
**Harry** is available only one time so the total count is 2 now.
**Saw** has 0 value, so we will not count it.

The expected output is -> Total Seller count  = 2

Comment: There are three types of `filters` in `Power BI`. Did You Try the `Filter` Option?

Comment: Isn't this basically subtracting to the total amount of people those who have a 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
Measure = 
VAR a = COUNTROWS(VALUES('Table'[Seller]))
VAR b = COUNTROWS( SUMMARIZE( FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Value] = 0), 'Table'[Seller]))

RETURN a-b
```

Comment: Is `COUNTROWS` more efficient than `CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(...` in terms of performance?

Comment: Yes. Distinct counts are very slow and countrows is as fas as it gets. Although on small tables, the performance will be miniscule and not material.